# What happens if you specify an allocator where the value_types are different?

Tags: c++

Say I declare `std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<char>>`. What's the worse that can happen? I ran it and didn't seem to run into any memory errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It results in undefined behavior. For allocator-aware containers like `vector` the standard specifies in Table 99:

> *Requires:* `allocator_type::value_type` is the same as `X::value_type`.

<sub>(Note that the same row also specifies that `allocator_type` **must be** a typedef for the template argument of the container-specialization)</sub>
And acccording to [res.on.functions]/2:

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases: 
> […] 
> —
>   for types used as template arguments when instantiating a template
>   component, if the operations on the type do not implement the
>   semantics of the applicable Requirements subclause (17.6.3.5, 23.2,
>   24.2, 26.2).

Comment: And just for completeness, `23.2.1 [container.requirements.general]` paragraph 14 shows that the requirement you mention applies to `std::vector`: All of the containers defined in this Clause and in (21.4) except `array` meet the additional requirements of an allocator-aware container, as described in Table 99.

Comment: @BoBTFish Fair enough. I don't think it's necessary to include that in the answer though, anyone that doubts that that is the case will see your comment :)

Answer (score -2):

I guess the compiler optimized it implicitly but the worst case would be undefined behavior

Comment: It's _always_ undefined behaviour. Doesn't matter what the compiler does.